# How to stop the pin to move along with map in MapKit

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, mapkit

I have implemented Maps and Pin in to it but when I Drag map Pin also moves with it. I want to fix pin in the center location of screen and Drag underneath Map.

Currently I Drag pin and where I drop it tells its lattitude, Longitude points.

I want to stop the pin to move along with map.

[image]

Comment: THis is not the idea of a map annotation. Annottaions have geographical coordinates, and therefore move with them map.

Comment: Yes I want to get geographical locations but donot want to move pin, PIN will indicate the location while map will move

Comment: I don't understand: If the user drags the whole map, then of course the pin must be moved, because it reprsemts an exacte geo location. Why it should not be moved? Then it would not represent its geo location anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the idea of a map annotation. Annotaions have geographical coordinates, and therefore move with the map.

What you want is a custom view (which looks like a pin) which you add to the viewController as subView. Your custom view is then parallel to the mkMapKit in view Hierarchy,  then such a view always stays on its screen coordinates.

Examples are: Cross hairs in the middle of the screen, ruler views, coordinates display, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIImageView *imgVew = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user_marker"]];
    imgVew.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 7, 17);
    imgVew.center=self.view.center;
    AppDelegate*appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.window addSubview:imgVew];
```

use this for your problem it will definitely work